# what is equivalent 0* |a* |b* |(a|b)*

Tags: regex, regular-language

I've been trying this exercise, but i donk know how to keep going. 
What is equivalent to:

```
 0* |a* |b* |(a|b)*
```

Beeing 0 the void language, i know that 0* = ε, so the regular expression is now :

```
ε | a* |b* |(a|b)*
```

I know that b* is contained in (a|b)* , as well is a*, because:

```
(a|b)* = (a*|b*)* = (a* b*)*
```

But its not the same, so at this point i dont know how to simplify this regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if both `a*` and `b*` are contained in `(a|b)*`, you can just remove `a*` and `b*` from your regex (because it's connected with an OR). Then you are left with `ε|(a|b)*`. Asterix means any number of repetitions, so if you select 0 repetitions of `(a|b)*`, you get `ε`. Therefore, your regex is equivalent to just:

```
(a|b)*
```

Comment: so, if i got an expression 'a' that is contained in other expression 'b', if i have a | b, i can just remove a, because b can accept all cases that 'a' acepts, but only with OR ' | ' ??, thanx

Comment: Real-life example. `I like everything that is a red cat OR a cat`. You can just remove the `red cat` because `cat` already contains all `red cats`. In your case, you have a series of `a` OR any combination of `a` and `b`. If you can build any combination, that obviously contains a series of `a`.